# Load HTML earlier than

Tags: php, html

Are there ways to load html codes before php codes? I have tried the code below. from Accounts.php it should `<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>`.

On the lougout.php:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = false;
$_SESSION['Username'] = "";

sleep(2);

session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
```

-- html code stuff that shows the page design --

```
<html><body> CSS and html codes </body></html>
```

After experimenting with the sleep command, i then knew that sleep delays PHP and html which didn't help at all... The problem is that it does not show the logout message.

Comment: `header` function can only be called before outputting anything in the browser .. try redirecting using javascript ..

Comment: php in an server side language so it will run first and then result is given in form of html

Comment: What do you desire, explain

Comment: The PHP code will execute first, when the client makes a request to the server, the PHP code will generate HTML to pass back to the client. Then the HTML will be parsed as soon as the client receives it. To help you you may need to re-word your question please read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can change your header('Location: login.php'); in: header( "refresh:5;url=login.php" );

You will be redirected after 5 seconds when the page is loaded.